# Where does the offset format of ISO-8601 formatted values in NodeTime come from?

Tags: javascript, iso8601, nodatime

While trying to parse an ISO-8601 formatted string in Javascript, I noticed that it cannot parse the string when the offset lacks the minute part. E.g:

```
Date.parse("2014-05-16T07:28:51.148412+02")
```

results evaluates to `NaN`, whereas

```
Date.parse("2014-05-16T07:28:51.148412+02:00")
```

evaluates to `1400218131148`. This was confusing me, as both NodaTime (where the string without the minutes gets generated) and Javascript seem to support ISO-8601. What is interesting is that different sources make different statements about whether the minute part is required or not: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) says it is optional whereas [this document](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) says it's not.

So what is the correct specification? Should I even file a bug for NodaTime that they don't follow the standard? And what would be a workaround? I can't seem to get NodaTime to produce the offset with minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noda Time follows the [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) specification (if you don't want to buy it, you can find draft specifications for free) correctly. However, the `Date` object in Javascript doesn't follow ISO 8601, but a format *based on* that standard.

If you look in the ECMA-262 specification (which applies to Javascript), you see that [`Date.parse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) must understand the so-called [Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). It's "based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format", and requires the time zone specifier, if present, to be `Z`, `+hh:mm` or `-hh:mm`.

Comment: +1 for the details on the standards, thanks. Then I guess I'll have to construct a custom pattern when serializing from NodaTime to Javascript, rather than relying on the default (which lacks the minutes in the offset).

Comment: Or just append `:00` to the output.

Comment: This seems like a bug (or at the very least, a shortcoming) in Noda Time to me. I filed https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=284.

Comment: FYI - while not called out specifically in the ECMA spec, the simplified date format supported in JavaScript is essentially [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt).

Answer (score 1):

See @Rhymoid's answer for information on the standards. I just add the solution that I finally took to parse ISO-8601 formatted dates in JavaScript.

There is a library called [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which is able to parse ISO-8601:

```
moment("2014-05-16T07:28:51.148412+02")
```

This returns a valid date object with the specified offset.